# Raytrace not clearing the costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, laser, costmap, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using navigation stack for 2d navigation of UAV. I am using Hokuyo Lidar for obstacle detection. When the laser scan sees an obstacle it marks the points in costmap as obstacle. However if during the later scans if it doesnot find obstacle in the same spot it doesnt clear the obstacles from the costmap.

I havemarking: true, clearing: true, obstacle_range:2 and raytrace_range:20 in my costmap_common_params.yaml file. By these parameters I assume when no obstacles are seen by laserscan it shold clear area of 20m in front of it. But that doesnt happen. It clears around 1.5m area in front of it no matter what the raytrace_range is. Any insight as to what am I missing or what can i do will be very helpful.

I am using ROS Indigo.

Thanks. Please find below my costmap param files

**costmap_common_params.yaml**

```
obstacle_range: 2
raytrace_range: 20
footprint: [[-0.2,-0.2],[-0.2,0.2], [0.2, 0.2], [0.2,-0.2]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.2

observation_sources: scan

scan: {sensor_frame: /laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan_filtered, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 0.5
  static_map: false
  transform_tolerance: 5.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 50.0
  height: 50.0
```

**local_costmap_params.yaml**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 50.0
  publish_frequency: 50.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 8.0
  height: 8.0
  resolution: 0.1
  transform_tolerance: 5.0
  planner_frequency: 5.0
  planner_patience: 5.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231599/raytrace-not-clearing-the-costmap/) by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2016-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on the laser sensor, if a scan does not hit an obstacle, different values can be associated with it: nan, inf, etc...
As a consequence, depending on the values on the /scan topic, the costmap may not treat it.

I am not sure how the hokuyo works, but you can try to add this line to your costmap config: `inf_is_valid: true` which means that the costmap will treat readings containing "inf" as valid, and therefore use it to clean or mark the costmaps.

If it does not help, you can try to filter your scan to remove and/or change values in its output to make sure they are valid numbers and withing min/max range. Check the [laser_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters) package.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2